# Fast cooking bone broth

Tags: broth

I have some deer bones I would like to cook into broth. All the recipes I found call for slow cooking many hours. Is it possible to fast cook it on a stove top (1-2 hrs max)?

Answer (score 15):

Yes, you can, if you use a pressure cooker.  You can easily create stocks and bone broth in less than an hour. I prefer this method. I make all my stocks in a pressure cooker.  I save a lot of time, and the flavor extraction is excellent.  I ramp up the alliums, because their flavor tends to get muted in the pressure cooker.  Otherwise prepare as if you were cooking your stove the traditional way.  Then, cook at the highest setting for 20 minutes to an hour.  Let the pressure come down naturally.  Strain.

Comment: Another option is to have a non-pressurized boil at the end with your aromatics.

Comment: you'll probably want to also add a bit more salt, I've noticed pressure cooked stocks tend to be a little more muted without additional salt.

Comment: @Sdarb I never salt my stocks.  I wouldn't recommend it.  Salting comes when I am constructing a final dish.  It is much easier to control the final seasoning that way.

Comment: Agreed with @Sdarb - the main reason I don't salt stocks is that they are often reduced (sometimes really reduced, like in demi-glace), so any salt added will be concentrated as well. I also have a pet theory that flavour extraction happens more easily in fresh vs salty water - but I don't know if that's true.

Answer (score 5):

Is it possible ? yes.

Will it give out the best result, ie. extract the maximum flavor, maybe not.

One way to help, would be to roast the bones at high temperature with some aromatic vegetables (onion, carrot, celery...) to get some color on the bones before starting your broth.